# How to make IntelliJ autocompletion NOT insert the full path in Javadoc

Tags: java, intellij-idea, autocomplete

My problem is that every time I insert a `@link` or similar in my Javadoc and complete a class, it inserts the full package path in front of it, even thought the class is already imported. For example if I have

```
import java.util.List;
```

and I write `{@link Li` in some Javadoc, and then completes that by choosing `List<E>` in the popup that appears, it still completes it to `{@link java.util.List}`. I'd actually prefer it to be `{@link List}` in any case, and then have the class imported automatically in any case. Event though I don't need it in the code.

Now why is that? Well, I read the Javadoc in my Java files, I rarely read my imports.

I use IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3.

Comment: It's quicker to type the word List than Li and select an option from a list... :)

Comment: Javadoc and imports are completely unrelated. The only way to unambigously refer to a class is by fully qualified name.

Comment: @Durandal It may be a bit ambigous at times, but it's more readable, and IntelliJ knows which one is the right one, when I press `[Crtl]+[B]` or `[Crtl]+[Q]` :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In `Preferences > Code Style > Java > Imports`, uncheck "Use fully qualified class names in javadoc".

[image]

Comment: This tab now allows you to use FQN only if the class hasn't been imported yet

Answer (score 7):

In `Preferences > Code Style > Java > Imports`, uncheck "Use fully qualified class names"

[image: Uncheck 'Use fully qualified class names']

Comment: Already did that. Doesn't work. However the one below "Use fully qualified class names in javadoc" does.

Answer (score 3):

### 2022 UPDATE

Intellij added a third, smarter option in `File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java | Imports`.

[image]